# Plugin or method to get similar functionality like django-reversion in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Is there any way to get similar functionality like django-reversion for Grails?

I mainly require the following functionality of the django extension on Grails:

> Roll back to any point in a model's history - an unlimited undo
> facility!
>
> Recover deleted models - never lose data again!
>
> Group related changes into revisions that can be rolled back in a single
> transaction.
>
> Automatically save a new version whenever your model
> changes Automate your revision management with easy-to-use middleware.

Use Case:
In Django I used it to create report based on the data on a particular date. In general, it is useful if any accidental update happens or you need to track any particular update and revert it. Also I think it is vital for all application dealing with sensitive data.

Comment: What's the use case for which you need this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about out of the box functionality, but what I often do is to build up a history:

Let's use a Book domain class as example:

```
class Book { ... }
```

with a simple histoty domain class

```
class BookHistory extends Book {}
```

this class inherits all properties from the parent class and will be stored in the same table as the Book class.

You'll then have to change the save and update actions in your controller in order to store the current Book instance as BookHistory.

Et voila, you have a history and will be able to check the state of an object at each point in history...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning audit trail plugin. Have you used it. Is there any function to rollback on a particular date.

Comment: Grails Audit Logging Plugin (with verbose mode on) have almost all functionality of reversion. Check http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging